# How to use 4N27 optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator, phototransistor, optoelectronics

I was wondering why the 4N27 optocoupler has a pin for base of the phototransistor - and of course how to connect it.

I've usually dealt with PC817 optocouplers and connected them according to the schematic.

[image: PC817 circuit]

Now I want to do the same with 4N27 (pinout on the picture below,) so do I have to leave the base pin floating, or pull down it?

[image: 4n27 pinout]

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48462/optocoupler-with-phototransistor-base-lead)

Comment: the base connection allows one to tradeoff excess On current saturation with OFF current rise time. If this makes no sense, ignore the base lead.